# Will CHEOPS use DSN or ESA ground stations, or both?

Tags: deep-space-network, esa, ground-station, cheops

The new ESA video [Cheops: Europe's exoplanet mission](https://youtu.be/EAIUJaaVJ9U) shows an animation of the space telescope communicating with a ground station somewhere in central Spain. The Deep Space Network indeed has a Madrid site.

Will CHEOPS use DSN or ESA  ground stations, or both?

[image: screen shot from Cheops: Europe's exoplanet mission]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CHEOPS Launch and Operations](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/cheops/cheops-launch-and-operations), the plan is to use the ground stations at [Torrejón de Ardoz](https://sci.esa.int/web/cheops/-/61430-cheops-ground-station-antenna-at-torrejon-de-ardoz) (east of Madrid) and [Villafranca](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/Estrack/Villafranca_station) (at the European Space Astronomy Centre, ESAC, west of Madrid).

> The sequence of ground passes includes 5 to 6 daily passes over the G/S of Torrejon (or Villafranca, since the MOC plans to use both of them depending on their availability). Each pass has a duration of  7 to 10 minutes, with 2 to 3 of these passes taking place in the early morning (around 7 a.m. local time) and 2 to 3 passes in the early evening (around 8 p.m. local time). All passes will be used to downlink the spacecraft telemetry at a fixed downlink rate of 1143 Kbps, which is compliant with the daily science and instrument housekeeping data generation of 1.2 Gb.

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of my question to be more neutral, since it looks like it will be exclusively ESA ground stations. Thanks!

Comment: somewhat related in Astronomy SE as it asks about the downlinking of data: [Why wasn't CHEOPS data taken during passage through the South Atlantic Anomaly downlinked in this case, resulting in gaps in photometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41054/7982)